# how to specify rotation angle in wolfram alpha

Tags: wolframalpha

I want to draw pentagon rotated to an angle of 45 degree. How to write code for this shape?

Comment: If you think your question has been answered to your satisfaction you should considering marking it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged 'wolframalpha' is assume that the 'code' you refer to should be entered at the wolfram alpha site. Entering `Pentagon rotated 45 degrees` there gives me a figure of a rotated pentagon.

In Mathematica:

```
WolframAlpha["Pentagon rotated 45 degrees", {{"VisualRepresentation",1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]